# android webview click simulation

Tags: android, webview, click, simulation

I was wondering if it's possible to load a frame from a website, fill a textbox, press submit button and take the results from that page? I need to do this in background so my webview is never showed, only an edittext and a textview are showed...

Answer (score -1):

Can't you do the stuff you mentioned using a http request?
What do you need the WebView for?

Comment: there are some pages in which some calculations are made with the data that user entered. and the result is showed in that page after calculations are made by server. can I use a http request for all pages?

Comment: give me the exact page and I can have a look.

Comment: an example of one page will be http://www.md5.cz/ even this can be computed from java easily, this is an example. my page does not exist yet, but will be soon launched.

Comment: For the page you gave me (md5.cz), you can use an http post request with the key "what". Eg: what=123455667. To find out what to include in different http requests you can load the given page in firefox and use the Tamper Data add-on to analyze what get's send when you actually press the submit button.

Answer (score -1):

You can use httpGet to get the pages and httpPost to post the results when the user presses submit. All you have to do is make sure that the post carries the data that the web page expects, and in the format it expects.

A good way to check what is required is use the Firefox Live HHTP Headers add on (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/).

For example the GET might be

```
URI uri = new URI(<your URL here>);
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
HttpResponse response = defaultHttpClient.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Then you put up your Android view with edit text boxes and buttons etc. When the user presses Submit, you get the text form the edit text box, and then construct a POST as below.

```
URI uri = new URI(<your URL here - without a host>);
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(urri);
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

List<NameValuePair> bodyParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
bodyParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(<parameter name string>, <parameter value string>);
// repeat additional bodyParams.add() as necessary for further parameters
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(bodyParams, HTTP.UTF_8));
HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost(<your host here>);
HttpResponse response = defaultHttpClient.execute(httpHost, request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Comment: but the user will not press submit button from web page, he will press an standard android button... I need to fill data into webpage form and submit it and get the response... But I don't know how to do it...

Comment: The code in my answer is what you need to send data when the user presses a button (eg Submit) in an Android View. I was only suggesting you use Firefox Live HHTP Headers in a browser to check the data that the web server expects - that is what goes in the bodyParams.